# Copy, remove and change value of element when condition is satisfied

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
 <pi:A xmlns:pi="urn:com.workday/picof">
      <pi:PG>
           <pi:EE>
                <pi:S>
                     <pi:EE_ID>ABC123</pi:EE_ID>
                     <pi:PGN>OS</pi:PGN>
                </pi:S>
                <pi:ED>
                     <pi:C>402B</pi:C>
                     <pi:SD>2017-04-01</pi:SD>
                </pi:ED>
                <pi:ED>
                     <pi:C>402C</pi:C>
                     <pi:SD>2017-05-01</pi:SD>
                </pi:ED>
                <pi:AI>
                     <pi:IRS>2018-05-01</pi:IRS>
                </pi:AI>
           </pi:EE>
      </pi:PG>
      <pi:PG>
           <pi:EE>
                <pi:S>
                     <pi:EE_ID>XYZ789</pi:EE_ID>
                     <pi:PGN>OR</pi:PGN>
                </pi:S>
                <pi:ED>
                     <pi:C>401A</pi:C>
                     <pi:SD>1996-04-29</pi:SD>
                </pi:ED>
                <pi:ED>
                     <pi:C>402F</pi:C>
                     <pi:SD>2017-03-01</pi:SD>
                </pi:ED>
                <pi:AI>
                     <pi:IRS>2018-06-01</pi:IRS>
                </pi:AI>
           </pi:EE>
      </pi:PG>
 </pi:A>
```

And xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:pi="urn:com.workday/picof"
 version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <pi:A>
        <pi:PG>
        <xsl:for-each select="//pi:EE">
        <pi:EE>
            <xsl:copy-of select="pi:S"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="pi:ED"/>
        </pi:EE>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </pi:PG>
    </pi:A>     
</xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name="EDS" select="pi:A/pi:PG/pi:EE/pi:AI/pi:IRS"/>

<xsl:template match="pi:ED">
    <pi:ED>
        <pi:C>
            <xsl:value-of select="pi:C"/>
        </pi:C>
        <pi:SD>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="pi:C='402F' and pi:C='402B'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$EDS"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="pi:C!='402B' and pi:C!='402F'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="pi:SD"/>
                </xsl:when>               
                <xsl:otherwise/>
            </xsl:choose>  
        </pi:SD>
    </pi:ED>         
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But my xsl doesn't do anything. I tried changing the code and was able to come up with a much better result but then the variable just keep throwing a blank value.

I just like that my final output will remove pi:AI, then copy the remaining. But if pi:C is 402B or 402F, then pi:SD must use the value from pi:AI.
So it must look.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<pi:A xmlns:pi="urn:com.workday/picof">
  <pi:PG>
       <pi:EE>
            <pi:S>
                 <pi:EE_ID>ABC123</pi:EE_ID>
                 <pi:PGN>OS</pi:PGN>
            </pi:S>
            <pi:ED>
                 <pi:C>402B</pi:C>
                 <pi:SD>2018-05-01</pi:SD>
            </pi:ED>
            <pi:ED>
                 <pi:C>402C</pi:C>
                 <pi:SD>2017-05-01</pi:SD>
            </pi:ED>
       </pi:EE>
  </pi:PG>
  <pi:PG>
       <pi:EE>
            <pi:S>
                 <pi:EE_ID>XYZ789</pi:EE_ID>
                 <pi:PGN>OR</pi:PGN>
            </pi:S>
            <pi:ED>
                 <pi:C>401A</pi:C>
                 <pi:SD>1996-04-29</pi:SD>
            </pi:ED>
            <pi:ED>
                 <pi:C>402F</pi:C>
                 <pi:SD>2018-06-01</pi:SD>
            </pi:ED>
       </pi:EE>
  </pi:PG>
```

Can anyone please help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: When you say your " xsl doesn't do anything", can you be more precise, please? Are you getting blank output, or the output exactly the same as the input? Or something else? Thanks!

Comment: @TimC what I'm getting is just                                                          
 <?xml version="1.0" ?>
 <pi:A xmlns:pi="urn:com.workday/picof">
      <pi:PG/>                                                                               
  </pi:A>

Comment: Are you not even getting any `pi:EE` elements output? Are you sure the XML in your question matches what you are actually using? See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiJb which shows you should get a lot more than you are currently getting then. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Valdi_Bo has given the answer to your question, but if you are keen to expand your XSLT knowledge, you might be interested to know you can simplify your XSLT greatly by means of the [Identity Template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform)

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This will handle copying across any elements you don't want to change, so you only have to worry about writing templates for the changes you need

So, to remove the `pi:AI` elements, have a template to ignore them

```
<xsl:template match="pi:AI" />
```

To update `pi:SD` where `pi:C` is "402F" or "402B", have template that matches those elements, and just update the specific ones

```
<xsl:template match="pi:ED[pi:C='402F' or pi:C='402B']/pi:SD">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="../../pi:AI/pi:IRS" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:pi="urn:com.workday/picof"
                version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="pi:AI" />

  <xsl:template match="pi:ED[pi:C='402F' or pi:C='402B']/pi:SD">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of select="../../pi:AI/pi:IRS" />
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note, as you are using XSLT 2.0, you could actually write the second template match as this...

```
<xsl:template match="pi:ED[pi:C = ('402F', '402B')]/pi:SD">
```

Answer (score 2):

Note line `<xsl:when test="pi:C='402F' and pi:C='402B'">` in your script.

`pi:C` can not be at the same time equal to `402F` and `402B`.

Change `and` to `or`.

Another correction: Change `<xsl:value-of select="$EDS"/>` to `<xsl:value-of select="../pi:AI/pi:IRS"/>`

The reason is that you unnecessarily copy all `pi:IRS` values.
You should copy only the "local" value.

Comment: Thanks! It worked after putting the <xsl:variable name="EDS" select="../pi:AI/pi:IRS"/> under <xsl:template match="pi:ED">